# R merging tables, with different column names and retaining all columns

Tags: r, merge, data.table, multiple-columns

I have a big job to merge two large data.tables.  This is new to me, and I need to demonstrate and explain to colleagues.  This is the reason for the paranoid approach, I'd like to randomly select some result rows to assure us all that the merge is doing what we think it is!  Here is my MWE, Thx. J

```
library(data.table)
first <- data.table(index = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"),
                    type = 1:5,
                    value = 3:7)

second <- data.table(i2 = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"),
                    t2 = c(1:3, 7, 5), 
                    value = 5:9)

second[first , on=c(i2="index", t2="type"), nomatch=0L]
```

Which is doing the job correctly AFAIK, and gives this result

```
  i2 t2 value i.value
1:  a  1     5       3
2:  a  2     6       4
3:  b  3     7       5
4:  c  5     9       7
```

However I would like, if possible to retain all columns from both tables such that the result would look like:

```
     i2     t2    index     type       value  i.value
1:  a        1      a         1          5       3
2:  a        2      a         2          6       4
3:  b        3      b         3          7       5
4:  c        5      c         5          9       7
```

Is it possible to retain all columns?

Comment: Maybe with dplyr::full_join(), but that is converting your data....

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this directly from joining. But there is no way that the join will give you wrong results. If you still want to check and assure you are correct, rename the columns so that both tables have the same column names `setnames(first, old = c("index", "type"), new = c("i2", "t2"))`. That way will will know that columns `i2` and `t2` on `joined` table, refers to both `first` and `second` tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible:

```r
second[first, on=c(i2="index", t2="type"), nomatch=0L, .(i2, t2, index, type, value, i.value)]

   i2 t2 index type value i.value
1:  a  1     a    1     5       3
2:  a  2     a    2     6       4
3:  b  3     b    3     7       5
4:  c  5     c    5     9       7
```